# using multiple selections and clicks with jquery selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, binding, selectable

I'm making an hour planning with jquery selectable.

The idea is simple: multiple selections possible. if clicked, hour is toggled on/off. if shift is pressed, fields turn red & are destroyed.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(event) {
        event.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        selecting: function() {
            $(this).find('td.ui-selecting').addClass('potential');
            if (event.shiftKey == 1) {
                $(this).find('td.ui-selecting').addClass('destroy');
            }
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).find('td.ui-selected.destroy').removeClass('ui-selected potential');
            $(this).find('td.ui-selected.potential').removeClass('potential');
            $(this).find('td.destroy').removeClass('destroy');
        }
    });
    $("td.ui-state-default").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');
    });
});​
```

See live example: http://studentify-static-pages.s3.amazonaws.com/calendar.html

Now. I cant seem to get the simple click right. Probably because im binding it before. Desired behavior: simple click (so 0 lasso) toggles ui-select.

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("ui-selectee ").on('click','td.ui-state-default' ,function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');
    });
```

Delegating the event to its parent

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that didnt do the trick either.. i've tried it with the .ui-selectee as well, didnt work. <tbody> does change classes though.